# How to join and query fields using SQLalchemy?

Tags: sql, flask, sqlalchemy

My tables:

*account* table - id,username,pasword

*post* table - id, stuff, user_id

**user_id** is the foreign key joining to **account id**

How would I query the username from account, if I have the user_id from post?

```
  posts = Items.query.all()
  for review in posts:
        name = review
```

this is giving me "items 1"

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You'll have to show your model code to answer that question-- if you've set the relation (assuming one account can have multiple posts, and one post can only have a single author/account) up correctly it'll just be `for review in posts: print(review.account.username)`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll want to have a join right inside your query

`.join(account, post.c.user_id == account.c.id)`

and then get it from `review['username']` in the posts loop